# NSWindow's top position is jumping during resize (auto layout)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, autolayout

I do heavily use auto layout in my new project, but I've got one issue related to NSWindow during resizing ...

- `NSWindow` is borderless window,
- during initial setup, frame of this window is set based on status item position and initial content view size (`intrinsicContentSize` of `contentView`),
- vertical anchor attribute is set to `NSLayoutAttributeTop`,
- horizontal anchor attribute is set to `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX`

... so far, so good. `NSWindow` is placed correctly, size is correct and everything looks good.

Whenever `contentView` is resized automatically because of auto layout, etc. final window position is correct, size is correct, ..., so again, so far so good.

What's the problem? When animation is in progress (window is vertically resizing), top of my window is jumping +- 1 pixel down/up/down/up/down/up/down/up/... until animation is finished. It looks pretty ugly ...

It behaves like this pseudo code ...

```
NSRect frameRect = window.frame;
while ( frameRect.size.height != desiredHeight ) {
  frame.origin.y -= 1; // Move window down by 1px
  [self setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
  frame.size.height += 1; // Increase window height
  [self setFrame:frame display:YES animated:YES];
}
```

... it looks like auto layout changes origin of window and then auto layout realizes that the height should be changed as well, ...

Anyone did see this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa, how can I missed it, it's because I do use `NSLayoutConstraint` for `height` of one of my views and I'm animating it via `animator` and it produces non integer values - so the `height` sometimes does contain real numbers and this is the cause for jumping top of `NSWindow`. Problem solved.

Comment: The problem of "jitter" during window resizing animations is well discussed in this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/213/